# html2pdf no funciona en php

Tags: php, html, pdf

Trabajo en un proyecto con php puro y necesito convertir un reporte en pdf usando la libreria html2pdf, genero la tabla de la siguiente forma
esta es la vista que pinta la tabla:

```html
<?php

?>

<style>
    table {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 600px;
        text-align: center;
        right: 100px;
    }
    table tr {
        background: #f8f8f8;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: .35em;
    }
    table th,
    table td {
        padding: .650em;
        text-align: center;
    }
    table th {
        background: #3C6D9C ;
        font-size: .80em;
        letter-spacing: .1em;     
    }
</style>
<h4><img src="../../images/image.png"><?php
                                        date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
                                        setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_co');
                                        echo strftime(" %A  %d de %B  de %G %I:%M %p")  ?></h4>
<!-- Define el cuerpo de la hoja -->
<div style="right: 100px;">
    <table border="1" > 
        <tr>
            <th style="width:9%;">Id Tiket</th>
            <th style="width:20%;">Asunto</th>
            <th style="width:40%;">Descripción</th>
            <th style="width:28%;">Fecha</th>
            <th style="width:15%;">Usuario</th>
            <th style="width:15%;">Estado</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($tikets as $tkt){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$tkt['id_tiket']?></td>
                <td><?=$tkt['asunto']?></td>
                <td><?=$tkt['descripcion']?></td>
                <td><?=$tkt['fecha']?></td>
                <td><?=$tkt['nombre']?></td>
                <td><?=$tkt['estado']?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
<page_footer>
    <div style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
        <span>Generado por: <?= $_SESSION['nombre'] ?></span>
    </div>
</page_footer>
```

para exportar el pdf desde la clase use esta función, $tikets es el arreglo que viene de la bd y se la paso a la vista para recorrer los elementos

```html
public function generarPdf($id)
 {
  $tikets=$this->consultaTiket($id);
  // $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'es', true, 'UTF-8', array(3,3,3,3));
  $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf;
  
  include ('archivo.php');
  
   $contenido = ob_get_clean();
  //  var_dump($contenido) ;
        try{
            $nomArchivo = "Reporte tikets.pdf";
   $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
            $html2pdf->writeHTML($contenido); 
            $html2pdf->Output($nomArchivo,'I');
   
        } catch (exception $e) {
            echo $e;
            exit;
        }
  exit;
 }
```

cuando tengo 11 registros el pdf se genera sin problemas, asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando vienen mas de 11 registros de mi bd se genera error en el archivo asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
intente limpiando el búfer pero no he obtenido el pdf con exito, agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Si me das un ratito te comparto el que use yo para pdf en php

Comment: Para depurar, en vez de crear el PDF envía la salida directamente al navegador y revisa que el código generado sea un HTML válido. Si no sabes hacerlo puedes usar el [HTML Validator de W3C](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Answer (score 0):

no se si ya has podido solucionar el problema. Te comento que yo utilice la libreria FPDF que puedes descargarla del siguiente enlace:

> http://www.fpdf.org/

Es muy simple de utilizar, te copio un ejemplo basico que tambien esta en la pagina oficial de la libreria junto a otros ejemplos:

```
<?php
 require('fpdf.php');
 $pdf = new FPDF();
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
 $pdf->Cell(40,10,'¡Hola, Mundo!');
 $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Incluis la libreria, creas nuevo FPDF, agregas una pagina, definis la fuente de la pagina (tamaño,tipo fuente,etc), creas una celda con 'cell'. Los numero dentro de 'cell' indican la posicion del texto que vas a poner en la celda. Seria como una especie de coordenadas. 
Espero te sea de ayuda.
Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta amigo,solucione con html2pdf , era abriendo el bufer en la parte inicial del documento